# Mini PC received higher voltage (19V instead of 12v) what hap

Tags: voltage, adapter

It was dark behind my desk and I've plugged in the wrong cable `19 V, 3amp` instead of the dedicated `12 V, 3amp`. The 19V adapter was from the monitor, and after I accidentally plugged it into my mini PC, it sparked and didn't turn on again after I've plugged the correct 12V adapter.

Further, when I now plug in the 12V adapter, the LED on the adapter goes away.

Can someone explain to me what happened? I'm not savvy in this area, but need to find an Answer to find peace with myself. And is this damage repairable or are the capactiors fried and more? I didn't smell much, just the typical Nintendo smell.

Answer (score 2):

The mini PC is broken, because components inside it were exposed to a voltage higher than what they were designed for. The damaged components probably caused an internal short circuit to form, which is why your 12V adapter light goes off. It's basically impossible to guess what's broken without at least some pictures from inside the PC, but it's highly likely that the damage is not easy to repair, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

The 19V was too strong for your mini PC and has broken some internal part(s).
An expert may be able to diagnose and replace the broken parts if presented with the PC in person,  trying to guess which parts are now bad over the internet is much harder.

If your disk does not use 12V  it probably survived.